# Is it possible to run all or part of a Hosted Linux VSTS Pipeline as a non-root user?

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline

I have some unit tests that test file accessibility, these are failing on Linux because it's running as the root user and the root user can write to read only files. Is it possible (preferably through yaml) to specify that some or all of the pipeline run as a non-root user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running builds and releases with hosted pipelines, which means the build running 
on machines managed by Microsoft, then you are actually using Microsoft-hosted CI/CD.

This uses our [pool of Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts) to run your builds, which do have some limitations such as below:

The ability to log on.

- The ability to drop artifacts to a UNC file share.
- The ability to run XAML builds.
- Potential performance advantages that you might get by using
  self-hosted agents which might start and process builds faster. Learn
  more

It's not able to select a non root user for now, take a look at this similar thread:  [Improve linux based agents to run under a vsts:vsts id instead of root](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/issues/45)